# XQE-V5-0011 Se ha encontrado un error de sintaxis de V5 en la expresión

Tags: cognos-11

Hi I am trying this expresion in a filter for a report, where [BRANCHID] is a field of query:
[BRANCHID] in (414,325,361,766,612)

XQE-V5-0011 Se ha encontrado un error de sintaxis de V5 en la expresión "[BRANCHID] in (414,325,361,766,612)"; se ha encontrado una señal no válida ",3896" después de "[BRANCHID] in (414,325".

I am trying with this one too: [BRANCHID] in ('414','325','361','766','612')

XQE-V5-0011 Se ha encontrado un error de sintaxis de V5 en la expresión "[BRANCHID] in ('414','325','361','766','612')"; se ha encontrado una señal no válida "'" después de "[BRANCHID] in ('414',".

Do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

If google translate is of any help, there's an invalid token in your expressions.  Interestingly, it is roughly in the same place for both attempts.

What is the datatype of BRANCHID?

A text data type would require that the things in the *in ( )* bit of an expression like that use single quotes to identify objects.  ('123', '345','567')

A numeric data type would require just numbers.

In addition, your locale can affect what the valid delimiter is.  In the English-speaking world it is the comma (,).  For you it might be something else.  I know that the thousands separator in some European countries is the period (.) and the decimal point is a comma.

The position of the error in both cases seem to be roughly in the position where the first delimiter is, so I would imagine that it is the most likely thing to control for, given what information which I have.

Given that, my troubleshooting would start at confirming the data type.  Next, try to use only one object, with the appropriate syntax, in the filter.  If that works, try adding a second one to it.  If that works, continue until you have your expression.  If it doesn't work, try changing the delimiter to one which is specific to your locale.